# button click not working on iMacro in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, imacros

The goal is to visit the specified url and auto click the play button.

Play button image:
https://prnt.sc/uanvxv

Issue:
imacro auto visits the url but not clicking the play button.

Here's my code:

```html
VERSION BUILD=1005 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=https://www.bbc.com/bengali/bbc_bangla_radio/liveradio
TAG POS=1 TYPE=MAIN ATTR=TXT:বিবিসি<SP>বাংলাবাংলাদেশ,<SP>তার<SP>প্রতিবেশী<SP>এবং<SP>গোটা*
FRAME F=2
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=POLYGON ATTR=ID:p_audioui_playpause.focused
```

Why the button is not auto clicking? Can anybody help

Answer (score 0):

```
VERSION BUILD=1010 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=https://www.bbc.com/bengali/bbc_bangla_radio/liveradio
WAIT SECONDS=5
FRAME F=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:audioButton*
```